# Object with arguments still displays initial values of reference variables

Tags: java, default-value, instance-variables

```
public class Date {

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public Date(int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear) {
    }

    public void setDay(int theDay) {
        day = theDay;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setMonth(int theMonth) {
        month = theMonth;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setYear(int theYear) {
        year = theYear;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void displayDate() {
        System.out.printf("The current date is: %d/%d/%d", getDay(), getMonth(), getYear() );
    }
}
```

+

```
public class DateTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Date myDate = new Date(20, 5, 2010);

        myDate.displayDate();
    }
}
```

**Result**: The current date is: 0/0/0
Expected result: 20/5/2010

I checked many times and I cannot see any mistake. Made sure that changes were recorded and restarted Eclipse. What do you think ? This is my first post here btw so sorry if it's not the correct form of posting here.
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: look at the body of your constructor. What are you doing with the parameters? How do you expect the fields to get values?

Comment: Point of terminology:  **methods** and **constructors** have arguments; objects do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is doing nothing to your fields so

```
public Date(int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear) {
}
```

initialize your files when you create your object :

```
 public Date(int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear) {
     day=theDay;
     month=theMonth;
     year=theYear;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **constructor** should be:

```
public Date(int theDay, int theMonth, int theYear) {

    this.day = theDay;
    this.month = theMonth;
    this.year = theYear;
}
```

Basically you need to assign value that you are passing to the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor you are taking arguements 'theDay', 'theMonth', 'theYear'. set them equal to 'day','month','year' class variables.

```
day=theDay
month=theMonth
year=theYear
```

inside constructor

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that, if you want to post an answer, it should (at the very least) be compilable?